# Get interval-based bandwidth results with iperf3 in Python

Tags: python, c

I'm using the iperf3 module in Python to measure network bandwidth between a client and a server.
I am getting the client result after waiting for 3sec as  i have set the client duration to 3ses, but i want to retrieve bandwidth results for every second during the test duration.
But i am getting the sum result of bitrate for 3sec.

Can someone help me with this?

```
server = iperf3.Server()
server.bind_address = '127.0.0.1'
server.port = 6969

print("Server started on {}:{}".format(server.bind_address, server.port))
while True:
    server.run()


import iperf3

client = iperf3.Client()
client.duration = 3
client.server_hostname = '127.0.0.1'
client.blksize = 1234
client.num_streams = 10
client.json_output = True
client.port = 6969
client.protocol = 'udp'


while True: 
    result = client.run()
    print(result)
```

I was expecting client result to be interval based like
interval     Bitrate
0-1          97
1-2          97
2-3          97

But i am getting the total Bitrate result for 0-3sec